# why does body height render as zero when it is specified as non-zero

Tags: html, css, window, height

Here is my code:

```
...
<STYLE>
body{
    position: static;
    height: 95%;
    width: 95%;
    border: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-color: black;
    background-color: pink;
    }
<STYLE>
...
<body>
<DIV id="div_1" >
    <DIV id="div_2a" >
        </DIV>
    <DIV id="div_2b"  >
        </DIV>
</DIV>
</BODY>
...
```

Although the height and width are specified as 95%, the width works but the height collapses, apparently because there is no content to the div's. This is totally counter-intuitive. To add
insult to the situation, the background color extends outside the border and fills the visible
page area. Is this a function of some sort of default body css declaration? If so what is it? 
And how can I stop this behavior? If the css is changed to reference HTML the behavior is intuitive
in that the border doesn't collapse but the background color extends outside the border. At this
point it seems like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You specify the height of the `body` at 95%, meaning that it will take 95% of it's parents height. So, giving it's parent the `html`tag a height, will also make your `body` take height.

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body{
    height: 95%;
    width: 95%;
    border: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-color: black;
    background-color: pink;
}
```

Comment: I added an html declaration and then the results looked like I expected. There is still the question why the back ground for the html extends beyond the border and now the background color for the body does not.

Comment: @user3861859 A quick test learned me [that the bg color of the body fluids indeed](http://jsfiddle.net/A4GXm/). But adding a [white background to the html tag](http://jsfiddle.net/A4GXm/1/) fixes the problem.

Comment: Also the body css also seems to include a margin around the border. So what is the default css for the body tag?

Comment: Change it to whatever you want... I believe all browser can render it differently. So when you declare it to be 2.5% of whatever you want, your sure that it will display the same in all browsers.

Comment: @user3861859, if the answer satisfies your needs, please mark it as solution (v-mark on the left of it)